# Angular controller not displaying object array data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

This is not displaying data, I am learning about controllers. Why it is not displaying data while it displays data in the video I am watching.

```
<div data-ng-controller="FirstController">
<input type="text" name="txtName" data-ng-model="typedName" />
<br />
Typed Name is: {{ typedName }}
<br />
Names:
<ul  >
    <li data-ng-repeat="person in Customers | orderBy:'name' |  filter:typedName  "> {{ person.name | uppercase}} - {{ person.city }}
    </li>
</ul>
 </div>
<script>
    function FirstController($scope) {
        $scope.Customers = [
            { name: 'Sita', city: 'Los Angeles' },
            { name: 'Ram', city: 'Los Vegas' },
            { name: 'Amit', city: 'San Antonio' },
            { name: 'Cat', city: 'Arkanas' },
            { name: 'Boushick', city: 'Pittsburgh' }
        ];
    }
</script>
<script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're following older videos where they mmight be using angular 1.2.

In latest version of angular, it's mandatory to specific app name and declare controllers under those modules. Though you can activate global controller functions via `config` but its not recommended.

So you need to make the following changes:

In your HTML,

```
<html data-ng-app="myApp">
```

NOw in your JS for controller:

```
angular.module("myApp", [])
   .controller("ControllerName", function($scope) {
      // declare your $scope data here
   })
```

> Why global controller functions are deprecated?

When you declare controller functions globally, It will be polluting the global namespace. Assume there is another library which is using the same function name, then your function would be overriden.

For example,

you have function `SimpleController` in your file. Assume some third party library you're using, they also use same name for some functionality.

They set,

```
window.SimpleController = window.alert
```

So it means your controller function has been overriden.

that's why it's been deprecated.

Comment: Thank you, you seem fair enough, its 2 years old video. At 29.00 in the video, they use same code without module it works. Perhaps its 1.2 version....But strange, I use 1.3 latest and it should be backward compatible....Fair enough, its mandatory now....thank you very much for pointing the reasoning....https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i9MHigUZKEM

Comment: You can make it compatible by adding allowGlobals in your `config` method. but it's better to avoid that's why its not recommended

Answer (score 1):

From the code you provided I believe its not working because you have not declared an `Angular Module` in your javascript and linked it to your html view via `ng-app`. Please check the working Plunker below.

http://plnkr.co/edit/fwwzZwODfZ9G5Ml1Y1MS?p=preview

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="FirstController">
        <input type="text" name="txtName" ng-model="typedName" />
        <br />
        Typed Name is: {{ typedName }}
        <br />
        Names:
        <ul>
            <li data-ng-repeat="person in Customers | orderBy:'name' |  filter:typedName  ">
                {{ person.name | uppercase}} - {{ person.city }}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script>
        angular.module('myApp', [])
            .controller('FirstController', function($scope) {
                $scope.Customers = [
                    { name: 'Sita', city: 'Los Angeles' },
                    { name: 'Ram', city: 'Los Vegas' },
                    { name: 'Amit', city: 'San Antonio' },
                    { name: 'Cat', city: 'Arkanas' },
                    { name: 'Boushick', city: 'Pittsburgh' }
                ];
            });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you, he is explaining module in next section in the video. However, he never used module, you can please check the video quick @ 29.00 time. It works perfectly for him.... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i9MHigUZKEM

Comment: I am very curious why it worked for him while I have the exact same code which is n't working for me. Could you please identify any difference at all?

Comment: @Deevinee Angular changed how Controllers work between 1.2 and 1.3, check out this for more details https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration

Comment: Thank you very much Mason for explaining and your quick code. Helps me. But I voted other answer, because explanation is to my basic level that I can digest.